"Palindrome recursive function" detects palindromes right but doesn't behave as expected

I made a recursive function in C that prints whather entered string is palindrome or not.
It gives correct answers,but left and right pointers have weird values,and printf prints 4 times for string "ana" instead of 2.Can someone explain me what is going on.
Code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
int palindrome(int left, int right, char string[])
{
    printf("stringleft:%c,stringright:%c,Left:%d,right:%d\n", left, right, string[left], string[right]);
    if (left == right)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if (string[left] != string[right])
    {
        return 0;
    }

    left++;
    right--;

    palindrome(left, right, string);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char s[20];
    int right = 0;
    printf("Please input the string:");
    scanf("%s", s);
    while (s[right] != '\0')
    {
        right++;
    }

    right--;
    printf("Right:%d\n", right);
    if (palindrome(0, right, s))
    {
        printf("\nEntered string is palindrome!  %d", palindrome(0, right, s));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nEntered string is not palindrome. %d", palindrome(0, right, s));
    }
}

I expected for string "ana"
left=0,right=2,string[left]=a,string[right]=a;
left=1,right=1,string[left]=n,string[right]=n;


Welcome! Before you go any further, please get into the habit of making your code readable, with proper indentation and appropriate whitespace. You'll be doing yourself a favour too. And please copy/paste the output as text into the question.

Function int palindrome() does not return a value, as you would know by enabling complier warnings.

"Please input the string" - is wrong. It should be "Please input the word" since you are only extracting a word. The scanf should also make sure it doesn't write out of bounds: scanf("%19s", s) and you should always check that scanf succeeded in extracting as many values as you expected to extract, in this case 1.

Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots (how to format code in posts). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

The big issue with your code is that you don't return in all cases from palindrome. In this situation the behavior is undefined. Fortunately the solution is simple: return the value of the recursive call.
You've also not accounted for cases where the left index might be greater than the right. This can be accomplished by changing left == right to left >= right.
int palindrome(int left, int right, char string[])
{
    if (left >= right) return 1; 
    if (string[left] != string[right]) return 0;

    return palindrome(left+1, right-1, string);
}

Note there is no reason to use ++ and -- rather than simple adding or subtracting from the values passed to the recursive call, and recursion isn't needed or desirable vs. a simple loop.
In main it's unclear why you're manually calculating the length of the string rather than simply calling strlen.
Without using recursion:
int palindrome(char *string) {
    size_t length = strlen(string);
    char *start = string;
    char *end = &string[length - 1];

    while (start <= end) {
        if (*start != *end) return 0;

        start++;
        end--;
    }

    return 1;
}


Perfect candidate for a helper function, e.g. change palindrome to palindrome_pos above and add int palindrome (char *s) { size_t len = strlen (s);  return palindrome_pos (0, len - 1, s); }. Makes for a simple call to palindrome (s) without having to code the indexing each time :)

And preserves the ability to call palindrome_pos() when needed.
